# file preview and re-upload using gcanti/tcomb-form

Tags: reactjs, tcomb, tcomb-form-native

I followed [File upload example](https://github.com/gcanti/tcomb-form/issues/112) and [this example](https://github.com/gcanti/tcomb-form/issues/360) I can now upload the file to s3. but when it comes to editing or replacing that file how should I handle that.

```
const CustomFile = t.irreducible('File', x => x instanceof File);

// MyModel
const BusinessModel = t.struct({
  logo: t.maybe(CustomFile),
  name: t.String,
}, 'BusinessModel');

// options
const options = {
  fields: {
    logo: {
      type: 'file'
    }
  }
};
```

My response object is

```
{
  "name": "business name",
  "logo": {
    "url": "https://some.url.to/s3/logo.png",
    "large": {
      "url": "https://some.url.to/s3/logo_large.png"
    }
  }
}
```

So how do I get response `logo` to fit in `BusinessModel` such that it shows preview if file exists.

`onChange` it shows preview of new file

`onSubmit` uploads the newly selected file

[is this something](https://github.com/gcanti/tcomb-form/blob/master/GUIDE.md#custom-factories) that I should be considering

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyFileComponent extends t.form.Component { 
  getTemplate() {
    return (locals) => {
      return (
        <div className="form-group">
          {
            getLabel({
              label: locals.label,
            })
          }
          <div>
          { this.renderPreview(locals) }
            <label lang="en" className="custom-file ml-3">
              <input type="file" className="custom-file-input" accept="image/*" onChange={evt => locals.onChange(evt.target.files[0])} />
              <span className="custom-file-control"></span>
            </label>
          </div>
          { getError(locals) }
          { getHelp(locals) }
        </div>
      );
    };
  }

  renderPreview(locals) {
    // your code
  }
}
```

This is what I did I'm yet to handle the errors highlighting but this works of course for single file upload.